# Get state of fx while animating with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am animating an element

```
$('div').animate({
    "right" : "0px",
    "left"  : "200px"
},
{
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if ( ? ) { // animation progress is 70% done or more
            if (!$item2.is(':animated')) {
                $item2.animate({width: 500}, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

How can I access the progress state on fx at the step?

**edit:**

Or this could alse do the job

How can I console.log() the `now` of `left` property being animated at each `step`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about a little trick ?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9dJw/)

```
$('div').animate({
    "right" : "0px",
    "left"  : "200px"
},
{
    duration: 1000,
    step: function(now, fx) {
        if ( fx.prop=='left' ) { 
            console.log(fx.now);
        }
    }
});
```